# Cannot add 2 key values to desired_caps for specific test function. Appium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-appium

I have a fixture of connection driver to appium server

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def appium_driver(request):
    base_desired_caps = {
        "platformName": "Android",
        "deviceName": "emulator-5554"
    }

    desired_caps = base_desired_caps.copy()
    marker = request.node.get_closest_marker("desired_caps")
    if marker:
        desired_caps.update(marker.kwargs)

    driver = None
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub", desired_caps)
        yield driver
    except Exception as e:        
        print("Driver connection error:", e)
        raise
    finally:
        if driver:
            driver.quit()
```

and test function for auth

```
@pytest.mark.desired_caps(appPackage="com.olsoft.mats.dev", appActivity="com.beepul.lite.MainActivity")
def test_auth(appium_driver):
    pass
```

But it won't work. For other test functions I don't need to relaunch the app, I need to go further in the app, that's why after auth there is no need in reconnecting driver

I tried this, connection driver response 200, but then I get 404, because I cannot locate element, cause I didn't launch the app through giving params appPackage and appActivity